# Route Email to external IP Cisco ASA 5515

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

I have a cisco ASA 5515X with two WAN connections and one LAN connection.

As far as I understand, I hace the firewall configured to allow SMTP traffic through WAN2 interface, but not through WAN1.

However, I'm having trouble sending email because the public IP is not matching the inverse DNS record. This record points to the public address of WAN2, but the email is labeled with the IP address of WAN1. How can this happen?

How do I force the outgoing emails to go through WAN2?

By the way, you will notice in the config file that WAN interfaces have private IP's. This is because there is an ADSL router between this interface and the public network.

This is my current CLI config:

```
config t

config factory-default

interface Management 0/0
ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0

interface GigabitEthernet 0/0
ip address 192.168.10.36 255.255.255.0
security-level 0
nameif Telefonica1
no shutdown

interface GigabitEthernet 0/1
ip address 192.168.203.1 255.255.255.0
security-level 100
nameif LAN
no shutdown

interface GigabitEthernet 0/2
ip address 192.168.20.36 255.255.255.0
security-level 0
nameif Telefonica2
no shutdown

interface GigabitEthernet 0/3
ip address 192.168.100.1 255.255.255.0
security-level 100
nameif EUS
no shutdown

route Telefonica1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.10.1 1
route Telefonica2 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.20.1 2

object network obj_any
subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
nat (LAN,Telefonica1) dynamic interface
!nat (LAN,Telefonica2) dynamic interface

object network obj_eus
subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
nat (EUS,Telefonica1) dynamic interface

policy-map global_policy
class inspection_default
inspect icmp
exit
exit

http server enable
http 192.168.203.0 255.255.255.0 LAN

http server enable
http 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 EUS

icmp permit any Telefonica1
icmp permit any Telefonica2
wr mem



! SERVICIOS ZURBANO



object network owaserver 
host 192.168.203.11 
nat (LAN,Telefonica2) static interface service tcp 443 443

object network RDPEUS
host 192.168.100.10 
nat (EUS,Telefonica2) static interface service tcp 3387 3387

object network RDPMEXHUB1
host 192.168.100.11 
nat (EUS,Telefonica2) static interface service tcp 3386 3386

object network RDPMEXHUB2
host 192.168.100.12 
nat (EUS,Telefonica2) static interface service tcp 3385 3385

object network RDPMEXHUBOLD
host 192.168.203.11 
nat (LAN,Telefonica2) static interface service tcp 3391 3391

object network exchange 
host 192.168.203.11 
nat (LAN,Telefonica2) static interface service tcp 25 25

object network TBOCAM
host 192.168.203.18
nat (LAN,Telefonica2) static interface service tcp 8081 8081

access-list OutsideToInside permit tcp any host 192.168.203.11 eq 443
access-list OutsideToInside permit tcp any host 192.168.203.18 eq 8081
access-list OutsideToInside permit tcp any host 192.168.100.10 eq 3387
access-list OutsideToInside permit tcp any host 192.168.100.11 eq 3386
access-list OutsideToInside permit tcp any host 192.168.100.12 eq 3385
access-list OutsideToInside permit tcp any host 192.168.203.11 eq 3391
access-list OutsideToInside permit tcp any host 192.168.203.11 eq 25

access-group OutsideToInside in interface Telefonica2


access-list AMZN_ACCESS_IN extended permit ip host 54.239.63.155 host 2.139.188.36

access-list AMZN_ACCESS_IN extended permit ip host 54.239.63.154 host 2.139.188.36

access-list acl-amzn-fra extended permit ip any 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0





access-list amzn-fra-filter extended permit ip 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0

access-list amzn-fra-filter extended deny ip any any

group-policy filter-fra internal

group-policy filter-fra attributes

vpn-filter value amzn-fra-filter


tunnel-group 54.239.63.154 general-attributes

default-group-policy filter-fra
exit


tunnel-group 54.239.63.155 general-attributes

default-group-policy filter-fra
exit

object network obj-amzn-fra
subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0

nat (EUS,Telefonica1) 2 source static obj_any obj_any destination static obj-amzn-fra obj-amzn-fra
wr mem
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you ask your ISP to disable the routing in their ADSL modem ?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but the problem is that the firewall still routes the SMTP port to the "blocked" IP in this case